# How can I start a minecart from a dead stop in the middle of a flat track (using redstone)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Creating minecart terminal stations are simple, but building minecart substations are more challenging. When a minecart is stopped either by running out of velocity or through a powered redstone brake, how can the cart be restarted?

There are obvious solutions to this such as set a solid block behind the cart and power the powered redstone rail, but this doesn't work if the cart is in the middle of a track. You can also put the minecart on a slope with a powered redstone brake and apply power, but this requires the cart to sit on a slope - which is awkward for a player to get into and out of.

So on a flat surface in the middle of a track, how do you get a minecart moving again?

Comment: Solutions involving the latest snapshots are fine too.

Comment: ok i read this question multiple times, what are you trying to accomplish? i get you want to get a cart moving again but you've already said you used powered redstone rail, although don't think you need a block behind it

Comment: ooo i get it now, just started trying to work it out and realized what you mean

Comment: @Paralytic Ya, unfortunately powering the powered rail under a stopped cart doesn't move it. If only..

Comment: @Resorath - It wouldn't know which way to make it move.

Comment: @SaintWacko well if they changed the powered rails to be more like redstone repeaters in that they have a back and front it would work just fine.

Comment: @Paralytic You might want to check out the Railcraft mod. It does exactly that, among other useful changes.

Comment: A slope can also make a minecart start on a powered rail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use two pistons, one on either side of the track, when you press the button to start the cart, one piston pushes a block into the track behind your cart, then trigger the powered track. Then the first piston retracts and the second one triggers, pushing the track back into place. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll try when I get home.

Comment: I use it pretty often. I also have another version that has the track sitting on a sticky piston, and it pulls the track down out of the way.

Comment: @SaintWacko Can you post screenshots of it? I know it's simple but I'm having a hard time visualizing it.

Comment: This works most of the time. However due to the nature of velocity the cart won't always stop perfectly on the powered rail brake, in that situation the block doesn't align properly. I'm not sure about the track on a sticky piston though @Saintwacko

Comment: Here is the finished design http://i.imgur.com/he6fX.jpg

Comment: whoa mine was way less complex then that

Comment: @Paralytic Yeah, I'm not quite sure what all the circuitry is doing in that one

Answer (score 2):

Alright I messed around, and an idea immediately hit me. Since I suck at explaining anything here is a picture.[image]

As you can see I have the Minecart on a track of Power Rail connected to a Lever which also connects to a Sticky Piston with a Dirt Block on it. You have to be in the Minecart for this to work, it works kind of weird, so I suggest messing with it a bit since it made me go backwards for some reason. Sorry its a simple build and a bit of an eye sore but i'm sure you can turn it into something better, if not let me know i'll work with it a bit.

Comment: Does this... push the player?? I didn't know you could do this.

Comment: yes, like I said it works weird but it did make me start going on the track without stop. I can make a video if you'd like? @Resorath

Comment: Interesting mechanism, but it doesn't meet the requirement of starting from the *middle* of the track.  Maybe adaptable, though!

Comment: @Shinrai Yes, it could be adapted to lower the piston down first, and then power it. More complex than the other answer but an interesting use case.

Comment: This looks related to how zipper elevators (used to) work.